# Check if "instanceof" is going to fail

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function A(){}
A.prototype = "Foo bar";

new A() instanceof A;
// TypeError: Function has non-object prototype 'Foo bar' in instanceof check
```

As you can see, if the prototype of a constructor is not an object, it will fail and throw an error. Is there a way to make sure `instanceof` will not fail?

```
typeof new A().constructor.prototype === "object"
```

and

```
typeof Object.getPrototypeOf(new A()) === "object"
```

apparently do not work.

Comment: Maybe wrap it in `try/catch`?

Comment: How about `typeof A.prototype === "object"`?

Comment: @Barmar How did I not think of that before? Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar Close, but `typeof A.prototype == "object" && A.prototype != null || typeof A.prototype == "function"` it is

Comment: But if you already know that the object is an `A`, why do you need to call `intanceof`?

Comment: And if you don't know if it's an `A`, how will you know what to use in `typeof XXX.prototype`?

Comment: Upon further testing I realized it is `A` causing the error, not `new A()`, and therefore checking `typeof A.prototype === "object"` will suffice.

Comment: why would you ever do `A.prototype = "Foo bar";` in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says `A.prototype` needs to be an object, so you should check for that:

```
function isObject(x) {
    return x != null && (typeof x == "object" || typeof x == "function");
}
```

but `isObject(A.prototype)` is not all you can do to assert an `instanceof` call won't throw. Going by the spec, you should test

```
function allowsInstanceCheck(C) {
    try {
        if (!isObject(C)) return false;
        var m = C[Symbol.hasInstance];
        if (m != null) return typeof m == "function";
        if (typeof C != "function") return false;
        return isObject(C.prototype);
    } catch (e) {
        // any of the property accesses threw
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `try/catch` to catch the error;

```js
function isItA(obj) {
  try {
    return obj instanceof A;
  } catch (e) {
    return false; //
  }
}

function A() {}
A.prototype = "Foo bar";
function B() {}
B.prototype = "Baz Quux";
console.log(isItA(new A()));
console.log(isItA(new B()));
```

Comment: While it avoids the unwanted effects of the type error, it returns false when it should return true. :-(

Comment: If the object has an invalid prototype, there's no way to tell if it's actually an `A`. It simply returns `false` by default because it doesn't know. See my example with `new B()`.

Comment: If `Foo.prototype` is not an object then objects created by `new Foo()` inherit from Object.prototype, so I guess *false* is OK since there can't be instances of Foo (not in a meaningful way).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not really an answer, but an interesting conclusion.

When a function is called as a constructor, if its *prototype* property isn't an Object, then the new instance is assigned the *intrinsicDefaultProto* as its `[[Prototpye]]` as described in [*GetPrototypeFromConstructor*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-getprototypefromconstructor).

In the process of creating a new instance, the *intrinsicDefaultProto* is passed the value of the *fallbackProto*, which seems to be (in Firefox at least), *Object.prototype*.

And since the *constructor* property of *Object.prototype* is Object, then testing whether the instance's constructor property references the candidate object won't work either.

```js
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype = 'A';
var foo = new Foo();

// foo inherits directly from Object.prototype, not Foo
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) == Object.prototype) // true

// foo also inherits constructor property from Object.prototype
console.log(foo.constructor == Object)  // true
```

So a circumstance in which *instanceof* fails likely points to more serious issues in the program design or implementation. Hiding such errors seems to not be a good idea (unless the intention is to leave traps within the code for future maintainers to discover).

Answer (score 0):

I use: typeof o.prototype === "function" && o instanceof f